# Prestashop - Page not found after protect admin directory

Tags: cpanel, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to protect my PrestaShop 1.6 admin directory via cPanel - Password Protect Directories, and when I enable the protection and try to access admin throw URL I'm redirect to 404 page not found.

I have other websites with directory protection and I don't have this problem.

Comment: Can you see what exactly the "protection" does? It probably changes filesystem permissions, but without seeing permission related information it's hard to see what the problem is. Unless someone had the exact same problem, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

cPanel password protect should work but it is difficult to say why it is not working. But there is an alternative way. Instead of password protection, you can restrict admin area using .htaccess. Just add following in .htaccess of your admin area:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 11.22.33.44
Allow from 12.34.56.78
```

You can add IP range or individual IPs.